# Persisting data in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, firebase

I am working in a Firebase app and I need to persist some data in the DOM, once the user logs in you are able to see the username and the email, but once you refresh the page, the user is still logged in but that data disappear from the DOM.

```
  <div class="item">
    {{::userDisplayInfo.name}}
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    {{::userDisplayInfo.email}}
  </div>
```

here the JS

```
  $scope.signIn = function (user) {
      auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: user.email,
        password: user.pwdForLogin
      }).then(function (authData) {
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once('value', function (snapshot) {
          var val = snapshot.val();
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.name = val;
            $scope.userDisplayInfo.name = $rootScope.name.displayName;
            $scope.userDisplayInfo.email = $rootScope.name.email;
          });
          console.log(user);
        });
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    };
```

so, what should I do to persist the user and email in the DOM ?

Comment: have a look at the documentation for onauth. That will trigger upon the reload and you can load the user's data from there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes but from onauth I can not retrieve user and email which comes from here ```var val = snapshot.val(); $scope.$apply(function (){$rootScope.name = val;})```

Comment: That code should work just fine on `$onAuth`. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-auth-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple for now, use $cookies:

```
// $cookies injected somewhere above
$cookies.put('userEmail', $scope.userDisplayInfo.email');
```

Then verifying if the user is logged in:

```
// $cookies injected somewhere above
if ($cookies.get('userEmail')) {
    // user is logged in
}
```

Comment: I need to download any library if so what's the name ? this works in all browsers ?

Comment: Yes, every browser. $cookies is a part of angular, you just need to include the angular-cookies.js script. Read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers support HTML5 Local Storage. First, check that the browser supports it like this:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // localStorage is OK to use
} else {
    // no localStorage support
}
```

then to set your data, just do this:

```
// Set
localStorage.setItem("user", userId);

// Get
var userId= localStorage.getItem("user");
```

Remember to clear the value when you log out, because localStorage persists even after the browser is closed and reopened.